# how to fetch json fom url in php

Tags: php, json

I am trying to make a php page tp print json data for this i m using one paraeter for which i needed to fetch json from another url.I used the code given in other stackoverflow ans but it always giving 0.I tried everything but it always giving 0.My php code is:

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['add']))
{
require_once('loginConnect.php');



 $bookname=$_POST['bookname'];




$url = "http://example/star_avg.php?bookName=$bookname";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json,TRUE);




 echo 'data' + $json_data->results[0]->{'num'};

?>
```

My json data from other url is:
    `{"result":[{"avg":"3.9","num":"3"}]}`

Comment: try `print_r()` for `$json_data`, and display the result here

Comment: Since you have passed `true` while calling `json_decode($json,true)`, you cannot access the data as object, try `$json_data['results'][0]['num']` instead `$json_data->results[0]->{'num'}`

Comment: @ Rohit Khatri thank u it works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You see `0` printed because you're performing an addition `+` between the string *data* and a non-existent property.  In PHP, to concatenate strings, do not use `+`; instead, use the dot `.` operator

In addition, because you're using `true` as the 2nd parameter to `json_decode`, what you get back is an array of arrays. Use the array notation `[]` rather than the object notation `->` to access members.

```
$json_data = json_decode($json,TRUE);
$num = $json_data['result'][0]['num']; //<- array notation
echo 'data: '.$num; //prints data: 3
```

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b90e1a8e97e24e1d819459de1573a5397744d034)

Comment: thank u very much it works perfectly.I need to ask one more ques that can i use more than pne url to fetch json differently

Comment: @NickyManali I don't understand the question

Comment: okk can i use more than one url to fetch json data.Like in above qus i have one url like that can i use two url in same php code to fetch json data.

Comment: @NickyManali sure. If you put the urls in to an array called `$urls`, you could then do `foreach($urls as $url){...}`. In each iteration of the loop, use `$url` to fetch and process the JSON from a new location